# Green numbers beside the items in smite?

Tags: smite

What are the green numbers beside the items in smite ? i don't think so they are any amount of currency or an amount of power the god will deal.

Comment: On what screen are you seeing the green numbers?

Comment: I have never seen any green numbers other than my FPS and Ping.

Answer (score 1):

Some items have stacks. (Book of Thoth, Warlock's Sash, etc.) The number on the item you're using is the amount of stacks it currently has. The items do have a cap limit. Check the details and passives of that item to see what it does.

From Smite Wiki about Book of Thoth:

"PASSIVE: You permanently gain 10 Mana per Stack, and receive 5 Stacks for a god kill, and 1 Stack for a minion kill (max. 75 Stacks). Additionally, 3% of your Mana is converted to Magical Power."